# Reading CSV files pertaining to financial recorts

Tags: beginner, file, csv, perl, finance

I have a number of text files (they are reports from a financial system) stored in a directory. Each report has a particular piece of text to search for (eg Report Total) and then a range of characters to extract for the value (e.g. position 78 for 10 characters).
There are a number of these reports - but no more than 200 so not a huge amount of processing or work required.

The premise of my solution is to maintain a simple CSV file with the report name, text to search for, start value for extract, length of characters to extract. Then, it is a simple case of updating this text file to add or remove the reports as necessary.

The script I have developed is below, and it works, but I would be interested in some critique as to how it may be made "better".

What needs changing/improving and why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Cwd;
use Text::CSV;

my $SrcDir="/data03/adudata/live/work/";
my $RepDir="/data03/adudata/live/archive/";
my $ReportList='pl_rec.list';
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
my @FileToRead;
my @TextToFind;
my @RowsOffset;
my @DataStart;
my @DataEnd;
my %ReportData;

chdir $SrcDir;
open my $fh, '<', $ReportList or die "Could not open file";
while (my $row = $csv->getline( $fh )) {
  push (@FileToRead, $row->[0]);
  push (@TextToFind, $row->[1]);
  push (@RowsOffset, $row->[2]);
  push (@DataStart, $row->[3]);
  push (@DataEnd, $row->[4]);
}

close ($fh);

for my $i(0 .. $#FileToRead) {
  open $fh, "<", $RepDir.$FileToRead[$i]. ".prn" or
    die "Could not open $FileToRead[$i]";

  while (<$fh>) {

    if (grep /$TextToFind[$i]/, $_) {
      my $extractValue = substr($_,$DataStart[$i],$DataEnd[$i]);
      $extractValue =~s/(^\s+)|(s+$)//g;
      $extractValue =~ s/,//g;
      $ReportData{$TextToFind[$i]} = $extractValue+0;
    }
  }
close $fh;
}

while(my($code,$value)=each(%ReportData)){
  print "$code,$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The point of filehandles is that it allows you to open more than one file simultaneously. So you could be reading the file list and the files you're searching through simultaneously.

Also, this:

```
if (grep /$TextToFind[$i]/, $_)
```

Is a a really convoluted way to write:

```
if (/$TextToFind[$i]/)
```

Overall, I'd do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $SrcDir = "/data03/adudata/live/work/";
my $RepDir = "/data03/adudata/live/archive/";
my $ReportList = 'pl_rec.list';

open my $list_fh, '<', $SrcDir.$ReportList
  or die "Could not open $ReportList: $!";

my %ReportData;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

while (my $row = $csv->getline( $list_fh ))
{
  my ($filename, $text, $rows_offset, $data_start, $data_end) = @$row;

  open my $fh, '<', $RepDir.$filename
    or die "Could not open $filename: $!";

  while (<$fh>)
  {
    next unless /\Q$text_to_find/;

    my $extractValue = substr($_, $data_start, $data_end);
    $extractValue =~ s/(^\s+)|(s+$)//g;
    $extractValue =~ s/,//g;

    $ReportData{$text} = $extractValue + 0;
  }
}

for (sort keys %ReportData)
{
  my $value = $ReportData{$_};
  print "$_,$value\n";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the time to respond :) and for the pointers! I'll add those to my learnings!

Comment: `$_` used in loops... See my comment on the other answer

Comment: Except that `while (<$fh>)` is valid syntax, and your suggestion is not. You may have meant `while (defined(my $line = <$fh>))`. However, using `$_` in a tight loop through a file is perfectly good, idiomatic Perl.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty good for beginner code.

Stating `use strict` twice does not make Perl any more strict. ☺  You have some extraneous requirements for `Cwd` and `Data::Dumper`.

A more proper way to append a filename to a directory is to use `File::Spec->catfile()`.

Since you operate on each row of the CSV file independently, there's no need to build up arrays like `@FileToRead` — just do the processing as you progress through the CSV.

Strings interpolated inside a regular expression are treated as regular expressions.  That is, if `$TextToFind` contains any "special regex characters" (e.g. `.`), they are not treated literally (e.g. match any character).  If you want to do a string match for `$TextToFind` rather than a regular expression match, you can quote it as `/\Q$TextToFind\E/`.

You can strip whitespace and commas in one substitution.  You missed a backslash when specifying the trailing whitespace.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use File::Spec;
use Text::CSV;

my $ReportList = 'pl_rec.list';
my $SrcDir = "/data03/adudata/live/work/";
my $RepDir = "/data03/adudata/live/archive/";

my %ReportData;

sub process_row {
    my ($FileToRead, $TextToFind, $RowsOffset, $DataStart, $DataEnd) = @_;
    open my $fh, "<", File::Spec->catfile($RepDir, "$FileToRead.prn")
      or die "Could not open $FileToRead";

    while (<$fh>) {
        if (grep /\Q$TextToFind\E/, $_) {
            my $extractValue = substr($_, $DataStart, $DataEnd);
            $extractValue =~ s/(^\s+)|,|(\s+$)//g;
            $ReportData{$TextToFind} = $extractValue + 0;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
}

open my $fh, '<', File::Spec->catfile($SrcDir, $ReportList)
  or die "Could not open file";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    process_row(@$row);
}
close ($fh);

while (my ($code,$value) = each(%ReportData)) {
    print "$code,$value\n";
}
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed the double 'strict' declaration - would be funny if it DID make it extra strict!!  As above, many thanks for taking the time to respond and show me different ways of achieving the result!

Comment: Don't use `$_`, instead implicitly state what you're doing/dealing with, i.e. `while my $line (<$fh>) { ..`.